# How to execute Java file from JavaScript on client's side

Tags: java, javascript

I have a code/class/script in JAVA that I want to be executed when someone clicks on a button/anything that I will handle.  What should be the code in JavaScript to launch that class/code/script/compiled program installed on the **client's** system?

Comment: Not possible without browser specific extension ...

Comment: but i have seen some sites using this

Comment: How about embedding an [applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/)?

Comment: i dont know much about java i will be working on it if i can get a script for this :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do with the program on the client-side.  If you want to call other programs on the client's machine, you will need a few things.

1. A code-signing certificate from an SSL vendor.
2. You need to create an class that extends Applet.
3. For just about anything you want to do on that client machine you need a class that implements java.security.PrivilegedAction.
4. You should really use the objet and embed tags instead of applet now.
5. Add the attributes to both the object and embed tags that allow scripting from Javascript.

Java code

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet
{
   public Object myScriptAction(String arg1, String arg2)
   {
       PrivilegedAction action = new MyAction();
       action.setXXXX();
       Object o = AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
       return o;
   }

   private class MyAction implements PrivilegedAction
   {
       public MyAction() {}
       ...
       public Object run()
       {
           // Do something here, Runtime.exec() or something else
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray, envarray, workingDir);
           return myobj;
       }
   }
}
```

HTML code with tags removed

```
    object name="myapplet" classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" width="1" height="1"
    param name="name" value="myapplet"
    param name="code" value="com.example.MyApplet"
    param name="codebase" value="<c:out value="/path/to/applet/"
    param name="archive" value="myapplet.jar"
    param name="scriptable" value="true"
    param name="mayscript" value="true"
    comment
        embed
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5"
            code="com.example.MyApplet"
            java_codebase="/path/to/applet/"
            archive="myapplet.jar"
            name="myapplet"
            width="1"
            height="1"
            mayscript="true"
            scriptable="false"
            pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download"
            noembed
                    Java not supported.
            noembed
        embed
     comment
object
```

The key is the mayscript and scriptable attributes that allow Javascript to call an applet.

You then use jarsigner to sign the myapplet.jar with the code-signing cert you get.

See this guide from Sun on mixed-browser Java plugin support.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#mixed

Comment: i just need to open a file on the clients system

Comment: Open like to read a file on the client?  I have used the above approach to launch applications on the client machine.  So using this approach you could open notepad.exe and give it the path to the file you want to open.  You might have to say more about what you are trying to open.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to deploy applet on your web page and then be able to call its method from javascript.

So, first you need appelet, i.e. class that extends Applet. If you already have one, you are done. Otherwise you have to create one and expose API that you already have.
Next you should deploy the applet on web page. Use either tag `<applet>` or `<object>` to do this. It is simple and you can find a lot of examples in internet.

Now you have to be able to call this applet from javascript. It is simple too. if for example you applet's name (I mean value of html attribute name) is myapp and the applet has method foo() you can invoke it from javascript like this: `myapp.foo()`

Here is an example:

```
<applet name="myapp" archive="myjar.jar" code="com.company.MyApplet"/>
<script>
    var result = myapp.foo();
</script>
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot for this. But can will this scipt work if i have java file converted it into a .exe one.

Comment: @kritya "..But can will this scipt work if i have java file converted it into a .exe one."  No, **thankfully.**  Java applets are sand-boxed by default, no browser maker in their right mind would allow embedding '.exe' files in web pages.

Comment: No ur getting it wrong this time I meant to say that the java file is in exe format and the user has already started that file.is that possible?